# Github Desktop commit not working with husky prehook

Tags: github-desktop, husky

I installed husky and set up a prehook, which works in the CLI. However, when I try to commit in the Github desktop, the "committing to..." button is loading forever. For context, .git file is located one level higher than package.json.

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "prepare": "cd .. && husky install dashboard/.husky"
}
```

pre-commit

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

cd dashboard
npm run test
```

I tried adding `PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` to pre-commit but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this comment here:
https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2518#issuecomment-323872966

Basically, my hook was running `npm run test`, and the test had `--watch` option so it never exited. Removing the command fixed the issue.